# Fade in and fade out DIV when in scrolled an item in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I have made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shubhamjha1000/vh7bu32q/2/)

```js
navlist = [];
$("#navlist a").each(function(i) {
  var thisLink = $(this);
  var thisId = thisLink.attr('href');
  var thisTarget = $(thisId);
  navlist.push({
    'anchor': thisLink,
    'id': thisId,
    'target': thisTarget
  });
  thisLink.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: thisTarget.offset().top
    }, 800);
  });
});
$(window).on('scroll resize', function(e) {
  $.each(navlist, function(e, elem) {
    var placement = elem.target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (placement.top < window.innerHeight && placement.bottom > 0) {
      history.pushState({}, '', elem.id);
      console.log('Hash: ' + elem.id);
      return false; /* Exit $.each loop */
    };
  });
});

//show phone triggering at height 150px from 1st DIV
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    var topDivHeight = $("#first").height();
    var viewPortSize = $(window).height();

    var triggerAt = 150;
    var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight) {
        $('.phone').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
        $(this).off('scroll');
    }
});
```

```css
#first {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #F06A59;
}

#second {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FB3E47;
}

#third {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFA306;
}

#fourth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #528AFC;
}

#fifth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #52FC6C;
}

#fifth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #52FC6C;
}

#sixth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #CFDA25;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 70px;
  font-family: agency fb;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 4px #000000;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 6px 4px #000000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-active {
  color: red !important;
}

.phone {
  left: 43%;
  top: 28%;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://fueled.com/assets/images/home/project-phone--iphone.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px 500px;
  padding: 70px 25px 75px 25px;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.phone-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 355px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
      <li><a href="#first" id="nav1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#second" id="nav2">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#third" id="nav3">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="phone" align="center">
    <div class="phone-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="main" id="first">
    <video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted>
      <source src="vid/vids.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="second"> </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="third"></div>
</section>
```

There you can see that when I scroll down the phone is shown triggering at height 150px. That is what I want so okay till here. But when I scroll back up to the 1st div it should fade out and hide. I tried to do it but failed. I want to make it in a way that its not shown in 1st and last div (it should only be shown in the middle div's). Say for example I have five sections there of divisions. It should start showing as it is now and should be visible till 4th div. Once 5th div comes into viewport it should fadeout and hide. And similarly when I scroll back to the 1st div it should fade out and hide again and repeat the process on scroll up and scroll down.

Please help me devs.

Comment: can you update the `jsfiddle link`

Comment: There would be problem in fiddle link. It is not opening.

Comment: you can just simply copy and paste it....

Comment: @ShubhamJha It's you who would like our help. You should really make sure that link and stuff like that works before you post the question

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I know bro.. I am trying but it seems that editor is not allowing me to do it.. don't take it personally please.. thats the reason I am not being able to do it and asked you guys to just simply copy and paste it which is not a big deal after all right?

Comment: If you read the "error" I bet it says, you cant paste an url to jsfiddle without   posting some code. aka there is the answer to the people why you cant paste the link

Comment: Post your code in the question, links to code do not count.

Comment: It says "Links to JsFiddle must be accompanied by code. Please indent the code using 4 spaces or by pressing CTRL+K" I tried it but still its not allowing me to submit and showing the same error.. can we just please move on from this topic and concerntrate on real problem please? its not really such a big deal to simple copy and paste a URL.. please guys I am in a fix here already..

Comment: @Downvoter... please explain..

Comment: Ok so I am giving here the fiddle link... easy now? http://jsfiddle.net/shubhamjha1000/vh7bu32q/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `else` statement to hide it if it dont match the `if`

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight) {
  $('.phone').css('visibility', 'visible').show().fadeIn();
} else {
  $('.phone').css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeOut();
}
```

Also remove `$(this).off('scroll');` then it should work

**NOTE** I've also changed your `.phone` class a bit

```
.phone {
  left: 43%;
  top: 28%;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://fueled.com/assets/images/home/project-phone--iphone.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px 500px;
  padding: 70px 25px 75px 25px;
  display: none; // <--- changed
  //visibility : hidden // <--- removed
}
```

**Update** update with answer to your question about last div

`var DivTop = $("#fifth").position().top;`
`if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight && $(window).scrollTop() < DivTop)`

Working example.

```js
navlist = [];
$("#navlist a").each(function(i) {
  var thisLink = $(this);
  var thisId = thisLink.attr('href');
  var thisTarget = $(thisId);
  navlist.push({
    'anchor': thisLink,
    'id': thisId,
    'target': thisTarget
  });
  thisLink.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: thisTarget.offset().top
    }, 800);
  });
});
$(window).on('scroll resize', function(e) {
  $.each(navlist, function(e, elem) {
    var placement = elem.target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (placement.top < window.innerHeight && placement.bottom > 0) {
      history.pushState({}, '', elem.id);
      return false; /* Exit $.each loop */
    };
  });
});



var mainTops = [];
$('.main').each(function() {
  mainTops.push($(this).position().top)
});



//show phone triggering at height 150px from 1st DIV
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var topDivHeight = $("#first").height();
  var DivTop = $("#fifth").position().top;
  var viewPortSize = $(window).height();

  var triggerAt = 150;
  var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;
  
  var count = 0;
  var number = jQuery.grep(mainTops, function(n, i) {
    if (n <= $(window).scrollTop()) 
    {
      count++;
    }
  });
   $('.nav ul li a').css("color", "#000");
   $('.nav ul li a#nav'+count ).css("color", "#fff");
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight && $(window).scrollTop() < DivTop) {
    $('.phone').css('visibility', 'visible').show().fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.phone').css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0}

#first {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #F06A59;
}
#second {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FB3E47;
}
#third {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #FFA306;
}
#fourth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #528AFC;
}
#fifth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #52FC6C;
}
#fifth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #52FC6C;
}
#sixth {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #CFDA25;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 70px;
  font-family: agency fb;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 4px #000000;
}
.nav ul li:first-of-type a{
  color: #fff;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 6px 4px #000000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-active {
  color: red !important;
}
.phone {
  left: 43%;
  top: 28%;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://fueled.com/assets/images/home/project-phone--iphone.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px 500px;
  padding: 70px 25px 75px 25px;
  display: none;
}
.phone-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 355px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
      <li><a href="#first" id="nav1">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second" id="nav2">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#third" id="nav3">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#fourth" id="nav4">fourth</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#fifth" id="nav5">fifth</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="phone" align="center">
    <div class="phone-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="main" id="first">
    <video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted>
      <source src="vid/vids.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="second"></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="third"></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="fourth"></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="fifth"></div>
</section>
```

**Updated code to solve color change on entering new section:**

```
var mainTops = [];
$('.main').each(function() {
  mainTops.push($(this).position().top)
});
```

```
var count = 0;
var number = jQuery.grep(mainTops, function(n, i) {
  if (n < $(window).scrollTop()) 
  {
    count++;
  }
});

$('.nav ul li a').css("color", "#000");
$('.nav ul li a#nav'+count ).css("color", "#fff");
```

Comment: how can I trigger it to hide when the last div say `<div id="fifth"></div>` comes into view as same as when its hiding on 1st div?

Comment: @ShubhamJha Try run it now and see if it is what you want

Comment: can I ask for one more little help if you don't mind ?

Comment: If it something to do with this question, sure. If its a about something else, please make a new question and then i will try help

Comment: same question.. changing navigation color when scrolling down like if on div 2 color of 2nd nav should change.. just a simple one... nothing much..

Comment: Try run it now my friend, There is a bit more code and a random color generator included

Comment: its changing all the nav color at once.. it want it changed one by one my friend.. like if scrolled to 2nd div then change color of that nav relating to that particular div...

Comment: working but again an issue.. its changing when the div is fully loaded and completely on screen and not when it just started to come into viewport.. due to this its not changing for the last div unless an extra div is added... if you get what I mean.. just as phone is coming when a little of 2nd div is just scrolled up same way at the same time the nav color should change just when it comes into view (when phone is shown)... thats the problem my friend :(

Comment: i am still waiting brother :)

Answer (score 1):

In code after showing the phone  you are using this `$(this).off('scroll')` this unbinding the scroll

This may help you

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
console.log($(window).scrollTop());
var topDivHeight = $("#first").height();
var viewPortSize = $(window).height();
 var lastDivHeight = $("#third").height()+viewPortSize;

var triggerAt = 150;
var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;
console.log(lastDivHeight);

if($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight && $(window).scrollTop() <= lastDivHeight) {
    $('.phone').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn();
}
else{
    $('.phone').css('visibility', 'hidden').fadeOut();
}
```

});

Comment: works but 2 issue.. fadeOut is not working and its straight away hiding out and I also want it not to be displayed in the last div (i mentioned this in the question)... so please update your answer :)

Comment: ok I removed `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` and its fading out now but 2nd part is still left... to be hiding out when last div comes into view..